# Is is possible to make System.out.print sort variables in a reverse order?

Tags: java, string, int, reverse, system.out

Is is possible to make `System.out.print` *sort* variables in a **reverse order**? I know I can use `Strings` and `reverse` it but I am wondering if its possible to do this with `System.out.print` directly in java. Thank you:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

Why?

> Invoking print or println outputs a single value after converting the
>   value using the appropriate toString method.

So you are only printing and nothing else and even with `System.out.format` you can not achieve this. Because:

> This class provides support for layout justification and alignment,
>   common formats for numeric, string, and date/time data, and
>   locale-specific output.

So, for a better solution, I made a simple function:

```
public static String reverseString(String wordToReverse)
{
    return new StringBuilder(wordToReverse).reverse().toString();
}
```